# Fixed header with multiple synced scroll

Tags: html, css

I have the following challenge, please see picture.

Zones A and B are fixed headers.
Zone A has no need to scroll.
Zone B needs to scroll horizontally.
Zone C needs to scroll vertically.
Zone D needs to scroll horizontally as well as vertically.

When the user scrolls **vertically** in either zone **C or D**, both zones need to scroll **vertically, in sync**.

When the user scrolls **horizontally** in either zone **B or D**, both zones need to scroll **horizontally, in sync**.

I know how to do this with JS, but **i'm interested if there's a pure CSS solution**. I've explored `position:sticky` layouts, but i haven't managed to get it all the way there.

[image]

Thank you for your time!